The shares of Germans and Canadians aged over 65
In the below sentence, I'm trying to use "share" in the sense of "percentage". Can I use it this way? This is a follow-up question to an old post of mine, which hasn't received a satisfactory answer. Here's the link to the old post.

...From 2000 to 2030, the figure for the UK is likely to keep increasing to end the period at 20% in 2030. The shares of Germans and Canadians aged over 65 are forecast to witness similar trends, climbing to 30% and 26% respectively in 2030.


The proportion of population over the age of 65 in three countries



Country
1988
2000
2030




Canada
16%
21%
26%


Germany
20%
25%
30%


The UK
14%
15%
20%




I've answered your first question. Does my answer there address your concern?

I wouldn't use "shares" that way. You've already used "proportion" in the table header. Either "percentages", "proportions", or "fractions" would fit.

@JackO'Flaherty Could you please have a look at the link in my OP? There are some examples from reliable sources which say otherwise. I would really appreciate it if you could share your thoughts there, or of course, here.

"The shares of Germans and Canadians over [some age]" is a misuse of the word share. Shares with an s means stock in a company. For example: The shares owned by him were worthless. share meaning percentage is always singular. For share top mean percentage, it has to be singular and non-countable. Also, forecast to witness is not right.

@Lambie So I guess forecast to see is also incorrect, isn't it?

We would just do this: x is forecast to follow similar trends. Only people witness situations. You might be better off on the Writing site.

I saw several sentences like: The retail trade is witnessing a sharp fall in sales. in dictionaries. Do you mean to say that this is only acceptable in writing?

You are misusing share.
A share is a portion taken (or alloted) from a finite amount or finite number of something.
If the chart showed, by country, a limited commodity like a precious metal, you might say something like "Germany has by far the largest share of platinum" and the sense is derived from the fact that there is a finite amount of this resource available on the planet.
To speak of nationalities in particular age groups as shares is to cast these nationalities in age groups as something taken or allotted or as something in demand because there is a finite number of them, which is not what your chart represents. It is not showing those countries claiming for themselves people over age 65 from a limited supply of people over age 65.
This is not an idiomatic use of "share":

Which share of the German population is over age 65?

You will find examples of it, but it is sloppy use of language and not a truly "mainstream" usage.
This ngram shows that the use of the word share in such constructions is a relatively recent phenomenon, and this ngram shows the relative frequency vs "percentage of the population". Bear in mind that a number of the works in which these phrases appear are not written by native speakers, which is one factor that accounts for the semantic drift.

What about this example from the New York Times: "Since 2000, the proportion of the prison population made up of whites and blacks had declined slightly; the share of Hispanics increased"?

Since 2000, the percentage of Hispanics in the prison population has been increasing.

Yeah but I mean I've seen "the share of" going with a group of people in many different places before. The above sentence from the NYT is an example. @Gotube also confirmed that it is used that way frequently.

I don't think you bother to read the answer closely, so it's becoming a waste of time to discuss these issues with you. Check out the ngrams I linked to in the answer.

I have read it but I have a good reason to doubt it, don't I? I am a non-native speaker and when I receive contradictory advice from different native speakers, of course I can't just follow any of you right away. This has long been a problem for me when using the site. Native speakers just don't discuss the disagreements together and come to a final conclusion.

Just because a word has recently become more popular and a portion of the people using it are non-native speakers don't mean that it's irrelevant, especially when I heard some other native speakers themselves confirm that they found this usage of the word natural. I really want to hear you all discuss this together.

Did I use the word "irrelevant". No. The problem with relatively recent semantic drift is that there will be a large number of readers for whom such usage feels wrong. Why opt for such a choice when there is another that will sound right to everyone?  It isn't a matter of being able to justify the choice by pointing to dictionary that has "blessed" it.
